# Creating array in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'd like to create an empty array in Shopify Liquid.
I tried to find some information in official documentation but there is nothing to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an array with the `split` filter.

If you are looking for an empty array, then you do this:

`{%- assign empty_array = ',' | split: ',' -%}`

Comment: Thank you!

{% assign empty_array = '' | split: '' %} - it works too.